# Pegar uma lista na View e passar para o controller c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

Tenho 2 listas que vem do banco de dados, uma de técnico e outra de fornecedores. Não estou conseguindo pegar da View e passar para o Controller. E como receber esta lista na controller

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o codigo:

Controller passar a lista para a view como ViewBag

```
            var listaTecnicos = new BLL.Tecnico.TecnicoListar().ListarTecnicosProduto();
        ViewBag.listaTecnicos = listaTecnicos;
```

*View Técnico*

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Cód.</th>
            <th>Técnico</th>
            <th>Quantidade</th>
            <th>Observação</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @{
            var cont = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.listaTecnicos.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr class=".itemTecnico">
                    <td class="idTecnico">@ViewBag.listaTecnicos[i].ID_Tecnico</td>
                    <td>@ViewBag.listaTecnicos[i].Nome</td>
                    <td width="100px">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.QtdProdutoTecnico, new { id = "qtdProduto_" + cont, @class = "money2 form-control somarProdutoTecnico", maxlength = "5", @placeholder = "00,00" })</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ObsProdutoTecnico, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>

                </tr>

                cont++;
            }
        }

    </tbody>
</table>
```

*JavaScript JQuery*

```
    $('#btnSalvarTecnicos').click(function () {

    var arrayTecnicos = $('.itemTecnico');
    var idDoTecnico = new Array();
    var qtdDoTecnico = new Array();
    var obsDoTecncio = new Array();
    var todos_tecnicos = new Array();

    function pegarosTecnicos() {

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayTecnicos.length; i++) {

            todos_tecnicos = {
                idDoTecnico : $('.idTecnico').val(),
                qtdDoTecnico : $('.somarProdutoTecnico').val(),
                obsDoTecncio : $('.ObsTecnico').val()
            };
        };


    };


    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SalvarTecnicos")', // to get the right path to controller from TableRoutes of Asp.Net MVC
        dataType: "json", //to work with json format
        type: "POST", //to do a post request
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //define a contentType of your request
        cache: false, //avoid caching results
        data: JSON.stringify(todos_tecnicos), // passar os parametros
        success: function (data) {


        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert("Erro! ao Salvar os com os tecnicos, Favor Entrar em Contato com O Suporte.");
        }


    });



});
```

*Controlelr*

```
    public ActionResult SalvarTecnicos(DTO.Produtos ListaTecncicos)
    {
      // aqui retorna ula lista vazia
    }
```

- DTO Produto *

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace DTO
{
    public class Produtos
    {

```
    public string QtdProdutoTecnico { get; set; }
    public string ObsProdutoTecnico { get; set; }
    public string QtdTotalTecnicos { get; set; }

    public List<DTO.Fornecedores> ListaFornecedoresProduto { get; set; }

    public List<DTO.Tecnicos> ListaTecncicos { get; set; }

    public List<DTO.ProdutoComTecnico> ProdutoComTecnico { get; set; }
```

}
}

Comment: Olá Denilson, seja bem-vindo à StackOverflow. O que você exatamente não está conseguindo fazer? Por quê não consegue pegar *da View* e passar para o Controller? Explique mais sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Analise este caminho:

```
public class Fornecedor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public List<Tecnico> Tecnico { get; set; }
}

public class Tecnico
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int FornecedorID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Geralmente em minhas Views (utilização própria), meus formulários de cadastro recebem uma DTO e uma lista de DTO agregada, conforme estrutura acima.

Na View faço a montagem da seguinte forma.

```
@model Fornecedor

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome):
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nome, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 50 })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@if (Model.Tecnico != null && Model.Tecnico.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tecnico.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Tecnico[i].ID)
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Tecnico[i].Nome):
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Tecnico[i].Nome)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tecnico[i].Nome, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 255 })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Na Action aqui monto da seguinte forma.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Cadastrar(Fornecedor pFornecedor)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
        return View();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return View();  
    }
}
```

Ao fazer o submit o MVC vai entregar toda a árvore, uma coisa importante é manter o indice de forma sequencial, caso utilize JavaScript para incluir itens na tela, o  indice deve ser refeito (0, 1, 2, 3, etc).

Não inclui mais código pelo fato de ser do básico de montagem de estrutura do ASP.NET MVC.

Avalie se esta forma atende suas necessidades.

Comment: não deu muito certo isso

Comment: Denilson, teria que ver basicamente o conceito utilizado na aplicação, quando chegou na controller, veio a lista acoplada? Já desenvolvi umas 5 aplicações utilizando este conceito e funcionou tranquilamente, como falei é um conceito a ser analisado. Outro detalhe é que aqui entrego o conteúdo via post do form do mvc @using (Ajax.BeginForm(. Só utilizo $.ajax quando faço preenchimento de combobox.

Comment: no meu controller passo para a view uma lista de tecnico coloquei na descrição, lá estou preenchendo a quantidade e uma descrição, queria pegar esta lista com o ID_Tecnico, Qtd, e a descricao passar para o controller onde pego esta lista para salvar no banco.